# In CPLEX OPL I want to create a condition using a variable

Tags: cplex, opl

```
forall(b in PitBlocks,d in DumpBlocks,t in TimePeriods)
      {
    //NonNegative waste:          
if ((Xbdt[b][d][t]) != 0) { (Xbdt[b][d][t]) >= 10};           
      }
```

Here Xbdt is a positive continuous variable. And I do not want its value to be between 0 and 10, otherwise it creates very small decimal numbers.

A variable is not allowed inside the if condition. Any suggestions on how could I achieve this differently ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called 'semi-continuous' variables. Erwin Kalvelagen has a nice succinct summary here:

http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/08/semi-continuous-variables.html

I don't know if OPL has direct support for semi-continuous variables yet. This post from a while ago suggests ways to implement this:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/modeling-semi-continuous-variables-opl

Answer (score 1):

```
forall(b in PitBlocks,d in DumpBlocks,t in TimePeriods)
      {
    //NonNegative waste:          
 (Xbdt[b][d][t] == 0) || (Xbdt[b][d][t] >= 10);           
      }
```

will work.

Full example in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosemiinteger.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 (nbBus40==0) || (4<=nbBus40<=20);
 (nbBus30==0) || (4<=nbBus30<=20);
 
 
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex

the solution you suggested worked perfectly :

```
forall(b in PitBlocks,d in DumpBlocks,t in TimePeriods)
      {
    //NonNegative waste:          
 (Xbdt[b][d][t] == 0) || (Xbdt[b][d][t] >= 10);           
      }
```